# Conflict between wxWidgets and boost::property_tree

Tags: c++, boost, wxwidgets

I'd like to use boost::property_tree in a wxWidgets applications.

However when I add the line

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
```

to a simple wxWidgets I suddenly get compilation errors:

```
||=== Build: Release in pulley_client_gui (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\Users\James\code\wxWidgets-3.0.1\include\wx\msw\winundef.h||In function 'HWND__* CreateDialog(HINSTANCE, LPCTSTR, HWND, DLGPROC)':|
C:\Users\James\code\wxWidgets-3.0.1\include\wx\msw\winundef.h|38|error: cannot convert 'LPCTSTR {aka const char*}' to 'LPCWSTR {aka const wchar_t*}' for argument '2' to 'HWND__* CreateDialogParamW(HINSTANCE, LPCWSTR, HWND, DLGPROC, LPARAM)'|
C:\Users\James\code\wxWidgets-3.0.1\include\wx\msw\winundef.h||In function 'HFONT__* CreateFont(int, int, int, int, int, DWORD, DWORD, DWORD, DWORD, DWORD, DWORD, DWORD, DWORD, LPCTSTR)':|
C:\Users\James\code\wxWidgets-3.0.1\include\wx\msw\winundef.h|69|error: cannot convert 'LPCTSTR {aka const char*}' to 'LPCWSTR {aka const wchar_t*}' for argument '14' to 'HFONT__* CreateFontW(int, int, int, int, int, DWORD, DWORD, DWORD, DWORD, DWORD, DWORD, DWORD, DWORD, LPCWSTR)'|
C:\Users\James\code\wxWidgets-3.0.1\include\wx\msw\winundef.h||In function 'HWND__* CreateWindow(LPCTSTR, LPCTSTR, DWORD, int, int, int, int, HWND, HMENU, HINSTANCE, LPVOID)':|
C:\Users\James\code\wxWidgets-3.0.1\include\wx\msw\winundef.h|94|error: cannot convert 'LPCTSTR {aka const char*}' to 'LPCWSTR {aka const wchar_t*}' for argument '2' to 'HWND__* CreateWindowExW(DWORD, LPCWSTR, LPCWSTR, DWORD, int, int, int, int, HWND, HMENU, HINSTANCE, LPVOID)'|
C:\Users\James\code\wxWidgets-3.0.1\include\wx\msw\winundef.h||In function 'HMENU__* LoadMenu(HINSTANCE, LPCTSTR)':|
C:\Users\James\code\wxWidgets-3.0.1\include\wx\msw\winundef.h|111|error: cannot convert 'LPCTSTR {aka const char*}' to 'LPCWSTR {aka const wchar_t*}' for argument '2' to 'HMENU__* LoadMenuW(HINSTANCE, LPCWSTR)'|
C:\Users\James\code\wxWidgets-3.0.1\include\wx\msw\winundef.h||In function 'HICON__* LoadIcon(HINSTANCE, LPCTSTR)':|
C:\Users\James\code\wxWidgets-3.0.1\include\wx\msw\winundef.h|311|error: cannot convert 'LPCTSTR {aka const char*}' to 'LPCWSTR {aka const wchar_t*}' for argument '2' to 'HICON__* LoadIconW(HINSTANCE, LPCWSTR)'|
C:\Users\James\code\wxWidgets-3.0.1\include\wx\msw\winundef.h||In function 'HBITMAP__* LoadBitmap(HINSTANCE, LPCTSTR)':|
C:\Users\James\code\wxWidgets-3.0.1\include\wx\msw\winundef.h|324|error: cannot convert 'LPCTSTR {aka const char*}' to 'LPCWSTR {aka const wchar_t*}' for argument '2' to 'HBITMAP__* LoadBitmapW(HINSTANCE, LPCWSTR)'|
||=== Build failed: 6 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 3 second(s)) ===|
```

This would seem to indicate that the wxWidgets methods can no longer handle UTF8 parameters, the ability to convert to UTF16 has been broken by the boost header file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `UNICODE` definition is inconsistent, i.e. it's defined (or not) when `<windows.h>` is included from Boost headers and not defined (or is) when wxWidgets headers are included.

To prevent this from ever happening, the recommended solution is to define `UNICODE` in your make or project file, so that it is defined on the command line. Chances are you already define `_UNICODE` there (if using MSVS projects), but this only affects the CRT headers and you need `UNICODE` as well for `<windows.h>`.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround.  If I include the boost header AFTER the wxWidgets headers then compilation is successful.